# Container shadow disappear when the child container background color is filled

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to get a Material Card with custom shadow (that why I don't use the Card's elevation), It work fine when the color of the child controller is set to white, but the shadow disappear (become much weaker) when the child container is filled with darker color like brown.

[image][image]

This is the code

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 16.0,
        left: 16.0,
        right: 16.0,
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.10),
              blurRadius: 8.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
          ),
          child: Container(
            /// If this Container is filled then the shadow is gone
            color: Colors.brown,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I even tried putting a CropRRect over the Card or container, but does not work. Can anyone explain to be why this is the case or anything I can do to keep the shadow the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not disappear, it's just a visual effect, you can try with:

```
    BoxShadow(
                     color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.50),
                     blurRadius: 18.0,
                      ),
```

and

```
 color: Colors.brown,
```

Comment: Thanks, I did tried this and it does show when I increase the opacity, but the problem is this cause a very inconsistent in design. Like if I want some cards to be filled with image and some with text (if no image is provided ) in a GridView then then each cell will have different shadows, which mess up the design. Is there any way to turn this visual effect off?

Comment: just use a BoxShadow with this color: color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),

Comment: Hi, thanks again, I tried with 0.3 and it still does not look the same as when the background color is `Colors.white`. And another problem would be that I have to set the Opacity to a specific value for each color of background and image I use. ><